# Не удалось получить COM-объект Virtual Box

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox

Господа, у кого была такая ошибка? Выручайте...) весь гугл на уши поднял, ничего не могу сделать (
ОС - Windows 10. Года два работала программа, не могу понять, вспомнить из-за чего вдруг перестала загружаться.. После очередного ребута ПК выдает ошибку и все.
Переделал кучу всего с инструкций с интернета, не помогает ничего.
Не удалось получить COM-объект VirtualBox.

Работа приложения будет завершена.

Completely failed to instantiate CLSID_VirtualBox: ERROR_SERVICE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT/0x8007041d.

Код ошибки:ERROR_SERVICE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT/0x8007041d (0X8007041D)
Компонент:VirtualBoxClientWrap
Интерфейс:IVirtualBoxClient {d2937a8e-cb8d-4382-90ba-b7da78a74573}

Я так понимаю ошибка на запуск службы VBoxSDS, при запуске этой службы выдает ошибку "Не удалось запустить службу VirtualBox system на Локальный компьютер.
Ошибка 1053: Служба не ответила на запрос.

1. Запускал от админа.
2. Переустанавливал (стоит последняя версия VirtualBox-7.0.10-158379)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте версию постарее, в VB ошибки это имхо частое явление

Comment: Пробовал, все также...

Comment: пишут, что для после отката надо .VirtualBox стереть, https://superuser.com/questions/1381001/cannot-start-virtualbox-on-windows-10-failed-to-acquire-the-virtualbox-com-ob

Comment: Я видел этот пост, у автора там другая ошибка, но я тоже пробовал все методы, что там предлагали, ничего не помогло

Comment: намучался я в своё время с VB, особенно после покупки oracle и перешёл на vmware player, а потом на hyper-v

Comment: @Pavel Gridin, да понятно, просто уже давно виртуальные машины крутятся на виртуал боксе, переделывать их на другой гипервизор это жесть ...